# InApp purchase not work for external (non play store) apk

Tags: android

I have integrated inApp purchase in my app and it functioning perfectly if i download app from play store. The problem is, when i install release apk directly in the device then it is not working and it's show below error,

```
the version of the application is not configured for billing
```

Comment: it wont work i guess

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure follow these steps to test

**1)** You've created an `apk` and you've published it to the `Google Play Developer Console` in Alpha, Beta or Production.

**2)** The app in `Google Play Developer Console` is NOT in Draft mode, but in Published (you'll need to make all the small circles with the check icon in them on the left side of the screen green before being able to publish).

**3)** You've set another test account than the one that's "attached" to the `Google Play Developer Console`.

**4)** The `apk` that you're using to test the purchase has the same version code, version name, and most importantly it's signed with the `same keystore` as the `apk` that you've published in the store.

**5)** You wait a couple of hours between when you change something in the dashboard in order for the changes to propagate. It takes a couple of hours to do so.

**6)** Make sure the `SKU` value is a valid `SKU/product` name (compare it with the one you've entered in the `Google Play Developer Console`).

**7)** You try to purchase an already purchased item. Get the purchased items and display them in the log to see if so. If so, then consume that product or refund the money to your test account. Note: you'll need to wait for the refund to propagate. It takes a couple of hours.

**8)** Make sure your `in-app products` are active.
For Alpha/Beta distributions, make sure you're signed into google (in your browser) with the test account and you open this link (marked with the red) and you approve to become a tester.

**9)** If you're using flavors to build `APKs` targeting different CPUs and you build for arm, armv7 and x86 and you upload them all to the store, remember to use one of them to test the in-app purchases. If you use a "universal" build which contains all the cpu libraries (basically another build than what's on the store) it won't work.